# How to activate color changing navigation on page reload past 10px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navigation which changes background color etc. when scrolling past 10px.
But if I stay past 10px and refresh the page it goes back to having a transparent background, until I start scrolling the page.

How do I make the function work when refreshing the page past 10px?

Code:

```
 window.onload = scrollNavi;

function scrollNavi() {

  $(window).scroll(function () {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > 10) {
        $(".navbar").css({ "background-color": "white", "box-shadow": "rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.2) 0px 2px 8px 0px" });
        $(".nav-item").css("color", "#707070");
        $(".logo").attr("src", "/images/logo/ccc-logo-new.png");
        $(".navi-icon").css("color", "#707070");
      }

      else {
        $(".navbar").css({ "background": "none", "box-shadow": "none" });
        $(".nav-item").css("color", "white");
        $(".logo").attr("src", "/images/logo/ccc-logo-hvid.png");
        $(".navi-icon").css("color", "white");
      }
    });
};
```

As you se above I have tried activate it with a window.onload but that doesn't seem to help.

Nav:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-xl navbar-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
    <img class="logo" src="/images/logo/ccc-logo-hvid.png" alt="" height="65">
   </a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs- 
   target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria- 
   expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `scrollNavi()`, all you are doing is registering an event handler for the *scroll* javascript event.
What you should do is store the scroll event handler in a function and call it on page load.

```
function scrollNavi() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 10) {
      $(".navbar").css({ "background-color": "white", "box-shadow": "rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.2) 0px 2px 8px 0px" });
      $(".nav-item").css("color", "#707070");
      $(".logo").attr("src", "/images/logo/ccc-logo-new.png");
      $(".navi-icon").css("color", "#707070");
    }

    else {
      $(".navbar").css({ "background": "none", "box-shadow": "none" });
      $(".nav-item").css("color", "white");
      $(".logo").attr("src", "/images/logo/ccc-logo-hvid.png");
      $(".navi-icon").css("color", "white");
    }
};
window.onload = scrollNavi;
$(window).scroll(scrollNavi);
```